# passing a variable to javascript function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, code-behind

I want to pass a string value to a javascript function from code behind. As it is a the moment I get an uncaught reference error explaining that the value is not defined.

```
var variable= txtVariable.Value;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Registering", "RegisterTheUser("+variable+");", true);
```

Advice perhaps on the correct syntax

This is the function

```
function RegisterTheUser(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have posted looks fine. I've used the following without any issue:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Registering", String.Format("RegisterTheUser('{0}');", myVariable), true);
```

Can you try using the example I have posted?

Comment: Your answer should indeed work, the code in the question would write `RegisterTheUser(contents of the variable);` The single quotes around the text are missing.

Comment: @Peter Yeah I should have detailed that in my answer. I had automatically added the quotes in my code sample without noticing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that your `RegisterStartupScript` is being executed before loading the function `RegisterTheUser`.

You need to sort out the order of the loading of the scripts or add some logic to call this function only after the `document` is ready.

In jQuery is done like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Registering", "$(document).ready(function(){ RegisterTheUser("+variable+"); });", true);
```

As sbhomra pointed in his answer, if the value is a string you might need to add single qoutes. Not needed if it's a number.